# React route not found on apache webserver

Tags: reactjs, apache, express

i'm working on a project where I use React on the front-end and express on the back-end for my REST API. I'm struggling with a route that is not found while on production on the apache webserver but working fine on the dev environnement : `/dashboard/exercice/<chapter%2Fexercice>`.

I followed react [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) to set up the SSR and when I run express to serve my app and the API it works well (when I visit localhost:4000).

Here is my virtualhost config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/noteslab

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # to redirect / to localhost:4000
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't have any errors on apache's errror.log.

Here is what the access.log says:

```
172.**.**.** - - [03/Apr/2022:13:04:26 +0200] "GET /dashboard/exercice/divers%2Fmonnaie HTTP/1.1" 404 493 "http://172.28.157.248/dashboard/repo/11047" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
```

And I use react-router-dom 6 to make routes with [loadable-components](https://loadable-components.com/) (react lazy doesn't do ssr)

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you really expect `GET /dashboard/exercice/divers%2Fmonnaie`? Shouldn't it have been `GET /dashboard/exercice/divers/monnaie`?

Comment: Yes, i really expect this have this url, the "divers%2Fmonnaie" is a path from the database that I decode to get all the data I need. If I do "divers/monnaie" it meens that I have to add another param each time I have another subdirectory in the database